# $S_0=75$ and $S_{n+1} = \frac13S_n - 6,\quad S_n = ?$.

Tags: sequences-and-series

$S_0=75$ and $$S_{n+1} = \frac13S_n - 6$$

How do I solve this relation and create a formula for $S_n$?

So far I got, $S_0 = 75$, $S_1 = 19$, $S_2 = \dfrac13$, $S_3 = -\dfrac{53}9$

How would I go about attacking this? I see no pattern or am I trying to find a formula in a wrong manner?

Answer (score 1):

Hint : look at $T_n=S_n-(-9)$.

Why the $-9$ ? Because $-9$ is the only  constant sequence satisfying the recurrence relation.

Answer (score 1):

Break into a homogeneous solution and a particular solution.  The homogeneous solution is simply $A (1/3)^n$.  The particular solution is a constant determined from the equation:

$$B = \frac13 B -9 \implies B = -9$$

So the solution is $A (1/3)^n -9$, and at $n=0$, it is $75$.  Thus $A=84$, and

$$S_n= 84 \left ( \frac13 \right )^n -9$$

Comment: Ok this I can work with. Can you explain how you got that though? LOL Really appreciate it! :)

Comment: Got which?  The homogeneous piece is simply $S_{n+1}=S_n/3$.  I chose a constant for the particular solution because the inhomogeneous piece is a constant.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of very elementary ways to attack this problem. You can try to ‘unwrap’ the recurrence:

$$\begin{align*}
S_n&=\frac13S_{n-1}-6\\\\
&=\frac13\left(\frac13S_{n-2}-6\right)-6\\\\
&=\left(\frac13\right)^2S_{n-2}-\frac13\cdot6-6\\\\
&=\left(\frac13\right)^2\left(\frac13S_{n-3}-6\right)-\frac13\cdot6-6\\\\
&=\left(\frac13\right)^3S_{n-3}-\left(\frac13\right)^2\cdot6-\frac13\cdot6-6\\\\
&\;\vdots\\\\
&=\left(\frac13\right)^kS_{n-k}-\left(\frac13\right)^{k-1}\cdot6-\ldots-\left(\frac13\right)^2\cdot6-\frac13\cdot6-6\\\\
&\;\vdots\\\\
&=\left(\frac13\right)^nS_0-\left(\frac13\right)^{n-1}-\ldots-\left(\frac13\right)^2\cdot6-\frac13\cdot6-6\\\\
&=75\left(\frac13\right)^n-6\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(\frac13\right)^k\;,
\end{align*}$$

and the summation in the last line can easily be eliminated if you know the formula for the sum of a finite geometric series. This formula should then be proved by induction on $n$, since at step $k$ we assumed that we’d correctly identified the pattern.

A slicker approach is to make a substitution in order to get a simpler recurrence. Let $T_n=S_n+d$ for some as yet undetermined constant $d$. Then $S_n=T_n-d$, so the recurrence $S_{n+1}=\frac13S_n-6$ becomes

$$T_{n+1}-d=\frac13(T_n-d)-6$$

or, after simplification, $$T_{n+1}=\frac13T_n+\frac23d-6\;.$$

If we set $d=9$, this becomes simply $T_{n+1}=\frac13T_n$, and it’s easy to see that this has the closed form solution $$T_n=\left(\frac13\right)^nT_0\;.$$ Now substitute the actual value of $T_0$, which you can get from $S_0$ and $d$, and reverse the substitution to get a closed form for $S_n$.

Comment: LOL You folks surely are math wizzes! I have no idea what you are all writing. Is this Calculus or something? Excuse me for my ignorance. My highest math attained is trig. Is there a simpler way to solve this and in a way that I can understand?

Comment: @Antonio: No, there’s no calculus here at all. What I gave you are the two most elementary systematic solutions that I know. Neither uses more than basic algebra up through the formula for the sum of a finite geometric series. Ewan’s hint is essentially for my second solution, and Ron has given another variant of my second solution.

Comment: LOL I never learned this in algebra

Comment: @Antonio: You learned all of the tools that I used (or certainly should have done). I’m sure that you did not learn this particular use of them, but that should not keep you from recognizing the tools themselves or understanding how I used them if you put your mind to it, especially in the second solution.